# PHP get values from array by comma separated list

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to get a small piece of code to work, but i'm kind of stuck.

When people submit a form, it saves a few keywords, but in numbers, to prevent people from changing the input with inspect element.
Every keyword has it's own number.

For example :

```
1 = test
2 = test2
etc.
```

When people submit the form, their input gets saved in a mysql database like this:

```
1, 2
```

What I'm trying to do from this point is I want to show keywords instead of numbers.
I've already made an array for the keywords:

```
$array = array(1 => 'test1', 2 => 'test2', 3 => 'test3', 4 => 'test4');
```

Is there a way to only show the values from the array that are the same as the numbers from the database?

Comment: Didn't understand your requirement completely, but if you want to have all the values of an associated array, you can use [array_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

Comment: @bhargavg what i meant was that i have a comma separated list, for example: 1,2. I also have an array, which is located in my question. What i'm trying to do is i only want the values from the array, that are the same as the ones in the comma separted list. 

So if my list contains the numbers 1 and 2, I only want the values 1 and 2 from the array.

Comment: "to prevent people from changing the input with inspect element" - huh? I think it's not really helping you the way you think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't store serialized data in your DB. Normalize your data appropriately instead.

That said:

```
$fromDB = array_flip(array_map('trim',explode(',',"1, 2")));
$keyMap = array(1 => 'test1', 2 => 'test2', 3 => 'test3', 4 => 'test4');
$intersection= array_intersect_key($keyMap, $fromDB);
```

The `$intersection` variable will hold an array containing only those values from the `$keyMap` array which have corresponding keys in the `$fromDB` one.

http://php.net/array_intersect_key

Comment: YW. You might have to trim the whitespace from each entry in the exploded array, in case the string from your database contains any between the commas.

Answer (score 0):

Easily done with MySQL query... example:

```
select KeywordName from MyTable where KeywordId in (1, 2)
```

You could then use a PHP prepared statement like [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) to pass the numbers to MySQL, and to fetch back the values into your array.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I misunderstood your question at first, but you can use this:

```
$list = "1, 2";
$keyArray = explode(',', $list);

$newArray = array(); //this will be your new array containing all the right values
forEach($keyArray as $key){
    $key = trim($key);
    if(isset($array[$key]))
        $newArray[$key] = $array[$key];
}
```

Comment: You're trimming an array in line 2.

Answer (score 0):

You could do as follows

```
$fromDB = array(1,2);

$keyMap = array(1 => 'test1', 2 => 'test2', 3 => 'test3', 4 => 'test4');

$keywords = array();    

foreach ($fromDB as $value)
{
    $keywords[] = $keyMap[$value];
}

print_r($keywords);
```

Answer (score 0):

> what i meant was that i have a comma separated list, for example: 1,2.
> I also have an array, which is located in my question. What i'm trying
> to do is i only want the values from the array, that are the same as
> the ones in the comma separted list. So if my list contains the
> numbers 1 and 2, I only want the values 1 and 2 from the array.

Use [`array_key_exists()`](https://www.php.net/array_key_exists)

Assume we have this;

```
  $s = 2; //2 was fetched from the database
  $array = array(1 => 'test1', 2 => 'test2', 3 => 'test3', 4 => 'test4');
  if( array_key_exists($s, $array) ) {
      echo $array[$s];
  }
```

You mentioned a comma seperated list.

```
  $csv = "2,1,4,500"; //Was fetched from the database
  $array = array(1 => 'test1', 2 => 'test2', 3 => 'test3', 4 => 'test4');
  foreach( explode(",", $csv) ) {
    if( array_key_exists($s, $array) ) {
        echo $array[$s] . PHP_EOL; //Final Output: test2 \r\n test1 \r\n test4
    }
  }
```